# When will flink expire it's TimeWindow result from Queryablestate?

Tags: apache-flink

I have implemented Total WordCount example with Tumbling window and QueryableState.

I have taken the **10 seconds** time window and when I print the result it display the correct result but when I use queryable state and make a query using the QueryableClient then it caches the last result of Time window even if the Time window change.

e.g, **Word count for 'Nirav' is 5 for time window 11:00:01 to 11:00:10**

When I query for 'Nirav' on time **11:00:50** then it returns the previous count 5.

So I have two question:

1. Is this default behaviour of Flink's QueryableStateClient which cache the last output for the same key until the new state for that key?
2. How can I clear the previous result when the Time Window finish?

Queryable Implementation is below

```
int sec = 10;
        Time seconds = Time.seconds(sec);
        text.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                for (String word : value.split("\\s")) {
                    out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
                }
            }
        })
        .keyBy("word")
        .timeWindow(seconds)
        .reduce(new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
            public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
                System.out.println("After time window fun:- a.word:" + a.word + ", a.count:" + a.count + ", b.word:" + b.word + ", b.count:" + b.count);
                return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
            }
        })
        .keyBy(wordWithCount -> wordWithCount.word)
        .asQueryableState("wordCountQuery", valueStateDescriptor)
```

Whole implementation

**SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.java**
    package com.nirav.modi;

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.JobGraph;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // the port to connect to
        final int port;
        try {
            final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
            port = params.getInt("port");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("No port specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount --port <port>'");
            return;
        }

        // get the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(10000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        // get input data by connecting to the socket
        DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port);

        ReduceFunction<WordWithCount> reduceFunction = new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
            public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
                System.out.println("reduce fun:- a.word:" + a.word + ", a.count:" + a.count + ", b.word:" + b.word + ", b.count:" + b.count);
                return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
            }
        };
//        ReducingStateDescriptor<WordWithCount> descriptor = new ReducingStateDescriptor<WordWithCount>("wordCountQuery", reduceFunction, WordWithCount.class);

        ValueStateDescriptor<WordWithCount> valueStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<WordWithCount>("wordCountQuery", WordWithCount.class);

        int sec = 10;
        Time seconds = Time.seconds(sec);
        text.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                for (String word : value.split("\\s")) {
                    out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
                }
            }
        })
                .keyBy("word")
                .timeWindow(seconds)
                .reduce(new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
                    public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
                        System.out.println("After time window fun:- a.word:" + a.word + ", a.count:" + a.count + ", b.word:" + b.word + ", b.count:" + b.count);
                        return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
                    }
                }).keyBy(wordWithCount -> wordWithCount.word)
                .asQueryableState("wordCountQuery", valueStateDescriptor);

        env.getConfig().enableSysoutLogging();
        JobGraph jobGraph = env.getStreamGraph().getJobGraph();

        System.out.println("[info] Window WordCount with Time Window Job ID: " + jobGraph.getJobID());
        System.out.println();
        env.execute("Socket Window WordCount with Time Window of " + sec + " seconds");
    }

    // Data type for words with count
    public static class WordWithCount {

        public String word;
        public long count;

        public WordWithCount() {
        }

        public WordWithCount(String word, long count) {
            this.word = word;
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return word + " : " + count;
        }
    }
}
```

**QueryStateWithWindowTest.java**

```
package com.nirav.modi;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.JobID;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.BasicTypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.queryablestate.client.QueryableStateClient;
import scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
public class QueryStateWithWindowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // the jobId to connect to
        final String jobId;
        final String queryableStateName;
        try {
            final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
            jobId = params.get("jobId");
            queryableStateName = params.get("queryableStateName");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("No jobId specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount --jobId <jobId>'");
            return;
        }
        try {
            ValueStateDescriptor<SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.WordWithCount> valueStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.WordWithCount>("wordCountQuery", SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.WordWithCount.class);
            QueryableStateClient client = new QueryableStateClient("truecomtelesoft", 9069);
            ExecutionConfig config = new ExecutionConfig();
            client.setExecutionConfig(config.enableClosureCleaner());
            ConsoleReader reader = new ConsoleReader();
            reader.setPrompt("$ ");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(reader.getOutput());
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String key = line.toLowerCase().trim();
                out.printf("[info] Querying key '%s'\n", key);
                try {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    CompletableFuture<ValueState<SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.WordWithCount>> kvState = client.getKvState(JobID.fromHexString(jobId), queryableStateName, key, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, valueStateDescriptor);
                    try {
                        SocketWindowWordCountWithQueryableStateWithTimeWindow.WordWithCount wordWithCount = kvState.get().value();
                        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long duration = Math.max(0, end - start);
                        out.printf("%d (query took %d ms)\n", wordWithCount.count, duration);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println("Query failed because of the following Exception:");
                    e.printStackTrace(out);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The succinct answer to "when will state created by `asQueryableState` expire?" is never.

`asQueryableState` gets translated to an operator which uses the incoming records  to update a queryable state instance via `ValueState.update(value)`. These values never expire, but are overwritten as new records arrive for a given key. In your test application, this means that the queries are going to return the most recent non-zero count for the given word.

Clearly this isn't what you were trying to accomplish. You could use a `ProcessFunction` to expire stale entries. To do that, you could explicitly create your own keyed managed state, and store with each count the timestamp of the window that most recently updated the entry. Then you would use a Timer to clear older entries.

See [this example of ProcessFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#example). To expire the state (which this example doesn't do), call `state.clear()`.

Comment: Could you provide any reference or example?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a pointer to an example of ProcessFunction.